# Enable/Disable real time monitoring in Windows

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I can't enable/disable real-time monitoring in Windows 10 using PowerShell ISE (as administrator). I have run the command `Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $false` for disabling real-time monitoring (in case it is enabled) and `Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true` for enabling real-time monitoring (in case it is disabled).

Comment: What errors are you getting? What is the value of `Get-MpPreference | Select-Object -Property DisableRealtimeMonitoring` after you run each command?

Comment: Are there Group Policies set?

Comment: @Cpt.Whale First I have run the command `Get-MpPreference`. It shows that the value of `DisableRealtimeMonitoring` is False. Now I want to make it true. So, I have run the command `Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true`. Now after running the command, I have again run `Get-MpPreference` command. But still it shows that the value of `DisableRealtimeMonitoring` is False.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik How to set group policy ?

Comment: Is "Tamper Protection" enabled? It will prevent you from changing the value:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/28561/how-to-enable-disable-tamper-protection-in-windows.html

Comment: Group policies may be set in a corporate or educational environment by IT staff. If it's you own PC, they could be set by an application or Registry entries, as well.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale after disable Tamper Protection, it works

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have been able to `Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true` is to disable "Tamper Protection" in the Windows Security App. Then you can run `Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true` and then `Get-MpComputerStatus` to see `RealTimeProtectionEnabled        : False` and set `fasle` to re-enable `RealTimeProtection`

A resource that might help: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-manage-microsoft-defender-antivirus-powershell-windows-10